# how to pass complete server URL to ajax call in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have a web page on server on http://techcodesolutions.com/test/urlHostDemo/callHost.aspx address. In that page i have [webMethod] that is

```
[WebMethod]
public static string method()
{
    return "This is message from server";
}
```

i want to call this method through my local web page using ajax with code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#aClick").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://techcodesolutions.com/test/urlHostDemo/callHost.aspx/method",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var b = data.d;
                    $("#lblMessage").text(b);
                },                    
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("no match");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

but it is show ajax error message. Could you guys please tell my how to call it.

Comment: What error exactly is it showing?

Comment: @AndrewHewitt 20 imaginary bucks say it shows "no match"

Comment: Try the type GET instead of POST.

Comment: @Kumar no, post will work just fine

Comment: it alerts message 'no match'

Comment: Error found in developer console:  `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load http://techcodesolutions.com/test/urlHostDemo/callHost.aspx/method. No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Where does this script present? Inside `techcodesolutions.com` or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: Your script must present inside `techcodesolutions.com` else you need to CORS will be the solutions.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS Sir i am calling the urlHostDemo/callHost.aspx web method from another file of local host and the script is present inside the local file

Comment: Hi sumeet. You need to examine the arguments (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to the error function (not just 'response') to get the full error. Further you can eye ball it if you use something like fiddler to watch the entire exchange. Hth

Comment: Further. If you cut and paste that URL into your browser, what do you get back?

Comment: You cannot do that. Either your script must present under `techcodesolutions.com` such as, `techcodesolutions.com/script.js` or CORS must be enabled.

Comment: Thank you all of you. Now its working when i put my urlClientDemo file to the same server where urlClientDemo file is present

Comment: i have one more question that here i deployed both file on same server but if i want to access my webmethod from different server could it possible that i just pass the webmethod url to ajax and i call the method?

Comment: No. from `onedomain.com` to `anotherdomain.com` is not possible without CORS.

Comment: Read more about CORS: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Try executing this first, `PageMethod.method(alert);` is it showing a message or not?